# Most efficient mental way to convert Decimal to Hexadecimal

Tags: computer-science, self-learning, binary

My question is as follows:  What is the most efficient mental way to convert Decimal to Hexadecimal?

I've heard of many methods.  Some people divide the decimal by 16 and find the remainder.  Others convert the decimal into binary and then convert that binary into hexadecimal.  One I am quite curious of is a method where the decimal is converted into octal, and the octal to binary, and the binary to hexadecimal.  Is this an efficient method at all?  I didn't really think converting decimal to octal was a very simple matter, but it could be a perfectly viable mental method.

The octal conversion works sort of like this:

```
123
 2 +
----
14
  28 +
----
173
```

To me this method seems confusing and prone to errors though.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say the most efficient *mental* way to go from decimal to hexadecimal is the division by 16 approach you mention.

123 in hexadecimal? That's 7 remainder 11. Write down the remainder (11), but in hexadecimal, which is B. Since the remaining number is less than 16, you can write that down to the left of the previous number, as well: 7b<sub>16</sub>!

It's a little longer with numbers of 256 (16<sup>2</sup>), of course, but the process remains the same. Let's try 657:

657 ÷ 16 = 41, renainder 1. Write the remainder: 1

41 &divide 16 = 2 remainder 9. Write the remainder to the left of the previous number: 91

Since 2 is smaller than 16, we can just write it down to the left of the previous numbers: 291

There you have it - conversion to hex in just 3 steps! Writing the numbers down as you go helps ease the mental strain, and since you have to write the answer down at some point, you might as well do it *WHILE* you're going through the process.

Comment: Explain to me how 123/16 = 7.11, because I'm getting 7.7

Am I missing something?

Comment: (16 × 7) + 11 = 112 + 11 = 123. Therefore, 123 ÷ 16 = 7 remainder 11. For the answer 7 remainder 7, 116 would have to be a multiple of 16, but it isn't.

Comment: Oh I get it now, so you first find what multiple of 16 is closest to that number without exceeding it. (for 123 thats 16x7 = 112) and then you find the difference between that number and the intended number and you write that difference number down, then divide whatever decimal number you have with 16 and repeat this process until the decimal number is below 16 at which point it is added to the sequence of numbers written down up till that point.

Right? Or did I just understand it in some roundabout way?

Comment: Don't have enough rep, but "renainder" -> "remainder" ... perhaps someone can fix it and flag my comment for deletion?!